# How can I convert a Composite ID stored in a MongoDB into a Morphia Java entity object?

Tags: java, morphia

I have a problem when `_id` is a composite id. Then, I cannot convert it into a Morphia Java entity object.

The JSON in my MongoDB looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "id1" : "SAMPLE_ID1",
        "id2" : "SAMPLE_ID2"
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity(value = "MyCollection", noClassnameStored = true)
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private MyObjectId thisId;

    //....
}

public class MyObjectId{

    @Property("id1")
    private String id1; 

    @Property("id2")
    private String id2;

    //.....
}
```

I am using morphia v1.3.2.

When I *insert* the object, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:76)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:850)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.updateKeyAndVersionInfo(Mapper.java:725)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.postSaveOperations(DatastoreImpl.java:1422)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.postSaveOperations(DatastoreImpl.java:1408)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1292)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:775)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:758)
>   .......

When I *select* the object, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:76)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:850)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:282)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:193)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
>       at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:147)
>   ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar setup that I got working. I think all you'll need to do is add @Entity to MyObjectId, so

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class MyObjectId { 

  @Property("id1")
  private String id1; 

  @Property("id2")
  private String id2;

  public MyObjectId() {
  }

  public MyObjectId(String id1, String id2) {
    this.id1 = id1;
    this.id2 = id2;
  }

}
```

I seem to recall that the no-args constructor was required for marshalling.